# Using the Consequence Rule

Tags: proof, hoare-logic

I have the following example that I have to prove

```
{a>7 ^ b>=0} n=a-b {n<a ^ a+b>=0}
```

Using the Consequence Rule I assumed that the P is true

```
{true} n=a-b {n<a ^ a+b>=0}
```

so logically, the Q should be true, but I'm not sure if that'd be enough.

Comment: Be aware that your statement is not true unless you replace `n < a` with `n <= a`. For instance, for `a = 8` and `b = 0` your precondition is true but `n = a - b = 8 - 0 = 8`, which is not `< 8`.